# Setting Principle.Identity.IsAuthenicated in Custom Authorization Filter

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, authorization

In a WebApi project I have a custom AuthorizationFilter attribute in which i take the token passed in the header and validated it with our SSO provider.

I want to set the Principle.Identity.IsAuthenicated to true but I can't as it is read only.

How can i create a custom principle with an identity that has the authenticated set to true when I tell it to?

here is what I have:

```
 public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var token = ParseAuthorizationHeader(actionContext);

        if (token == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }

        if (this.AuthorizeToken(token))  //this just validates the token with our SSO
        {
            // how would I set this?
            actionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated 
        }



    }
```

Comment: You have authorized token but have you authenticated the user? That is Authenticated property is based on having an actual Identity.

Comment: I am authenticating the user against Okta so not windows auth. They authenticate on the client side and on every request to the API they will provide the authentication token, which I will validate in a filter.